# Create sparse matrix from dataframe

Tags: python

How can I create a matrix of ocurrences from a dataframe of 2 columns? Im working with a DNS dataset (100 JSON files) that each file represents one day of DNS traffic. I'm making a subset of IP's directions from my interest and I want to create a sparse matrix (0s and 1s) of its ocurrences. Lets say I have 8 real IP directions from my dataset that look like this:

[image]

Since my interest are only `s_ip` and `dns_query` (the source IP and the DNS query searched), Im filtering the dataset by this columns and the IPs of my interest:`['10.0.0.31','10.0.0.60','10.0.0.33','10.0.0.32','10.0.0.42','10.0.0.44','10.0.0.34','10.0.0.29']`.

A filtered subset of my first IP of the list looks like this:

[image]

How can I create a sparse matrix &/or feature vectors from it? I've tried with CountVectorizer and HashVectorizer sucessless. The main idea is to have a matrix that, the first 8 rows represents one day of `dns_query` values. This means that for example the first row (first IP of interest) could have *n* numbers of columns (`dns_query` values in one JSON FILE (one day))

Something like using this example of sklearn, where the rows represent the first 4 IPs and the columns are the ocurrence of the `dns_query` values

```py
In [7]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [8]: corpus = [
   ...:     'This is the first document.',
   ...:     'This document is the second document.',
   ...:     'And this is the third one.',
   ...:     'Is this the first document?',]

In [9]: vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

In [10]: X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

In [11]: vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
Out[11]:
array(['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third',
       'this'], dtype=object)

In [12]: print(X.toarray())
[[0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]]

In [13]:
```

I've created a [MWE](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WnUVZH6yTgwNiTfjRsXPhIySdrQKs7lB?usp=sharing) in colab. Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: So, the database "key" here is `(s_ip,dns_query)`, and you want a count of how many times each pair occurs?

Comment: Basically, yes. I've added a dummy example of the matrix I want to create. I want it this way because Im using multinomial naive bayes (multiclass due to the 8 users) algorithm to predict the IP of certain query. Even if  I read the JSON as raw text, would it be easier to solve this? TIA